# Change WinJS data-win-bind using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, winjs

```
<div class="companyTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <div class='templDiv'>
        <h4 class='templText' data-win-bind="textContent: name"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

At some point I need to change the template's binding. How can I change "textContent: name" binding to "textContent: address" binding using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the HTML as Joel suggests, you need to call WinJS.Binding.processAll on the containing element with its data source to update the actual bindings.

That is, the declarative format with data-win-bind are just instructions to processAll for how it uses [WinJS.Binding.bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229803.aspx) or the data source's [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700602.aspx) method (which comes from a mixin) to set up the actual relationships.

The former, WinJS.Binding.bind, uses a binding descriptor to set up relationships between arbitrary sources and targets; the instance bind method has the source defined already.

Knowing this, you can use one of these bind methods to change the binding at runtime. It's a little too much to describe it here, so your best resource is to look at the [Programming binding sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ProgrammaticBinding-de038b64). I also discuss the subject on pages 313-315 of me free ebook, *[Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition.](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2)* (the whole chapter is about data binding).

Most likely you'll want to skip the declarative HTML to set up the initial binding, and just do it in code from the get-go. Then you can parameterize that code to just hand it a new source property when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 var theTags = document.getElementsByTagName('h4');    
 theTags[0].setAttribute('data-win-bind', 'textContent: address')
```